# I want to make "unread" and "already read" system in parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I want to make "unread" and "already read" system in parse.com

How to make a system that my following user post comment do not show after once seen.
for example RSS reeder.

Comment: Be a bit more specific please, what do you mean by 'system'. I think you may mean table? And by unread and already read you mean fields? Just trying to understand your question a bit more to help out

Comment: thank you for reply. the "unread" and "already read" system mean is like this photos. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yq0afrrdncvyv1h/AABPwKMoc4K0_3voRKdr9KUEa?dl=0